# MISRA 11.3: cast from int to pointer

Tags: c, misra

I have one question on how to solve MISRA 2004 11.3 violation.

The code is as follows:

```
tm_uint8 read( tm_uint8* data)
{
data[0] = *((tm_uint8*)0x00003DD2); 
data[1] = *((tm_uint8*)0x00003DD3);
data[2] = *((tm_uint8*)0x00003DD4);
}
```

I want to write the value stored at the physical address. It compiles but I have a MISRA violation for 11.3. I want to solve it. Can anyone help me with that?

Comment: The function should return a value. Also, you only need to cast the first pointer which you can then offset from (or memcpy)

Answer (score 2):

The rationale behind this rule is that MISRA worries about misaligned access when casting from an integer to a pointer. In your case, I assume `tm_uint8_t` is 1 byte, so alignment shouldn't be an issue here. In that case, the warning is simply a false positive and you can ignore it. This is an advisory rule, so you don't need to raise a deviation.

There is no other work-around, except never working with absolute addresses. Which is most likely not an option here. As you can tell, this rule is very cumbersome when writing hardware-related code, there is just no way such code can follow the rule.

Comment: While you don't need a Deviation, contrary to popular belief, you should not "simply ignore" an Advisory Rule... you should still document why the Rule is not being applied - even if this is done in the Company- or Project-level coding standards.

Comment: @Andrew I think most companies do that too. But this also means that the amount of "clutter" advisory rules in the document needs to be reduced. MISRA-C:2012 11.4 simply can't be followed in any form of microcontroller system. Same with 1.2. And then there's 5.9 which isn't feasible to follow in _any_ program and 15.5 which completely lacks any legitimate rationale. If we force people to write documentation about why they don't follow all these weak and often irrational advisory rules, that only makes MISRA-C less canonical, more cumbersome and more bureaucratic.

Comment: As for how I document these Advisory rules in my own MISRA implementations, I write an essay in the coding standard explaining why the rule isn't rational. This is fine as per 6.2.3 "alternative arrangements should be made for documenting non-compliances". I would rather not have to add this extra bureaucracy to the coding standard. Though most of the time, the Advisory MISRA rule can be replaced with one that makes more sense, such as the case of 15.5 where you can instead set a rule that multiple return statements should only be used if they make the code _more_ readable and safe.

Comment: My coding standards disapply some MISRA Rules too :-)  But the point I was making is that you shouldn't "just ignore" them... you should document (even briefly!) the decision,  After all, the Compliance Statement requires that.

Answer (score 1):

Note: MISRA-C:2004 Rule 11.3 is equivalent to MISRA C:2012 Rule 11.4

It is accepted that some MISRA C/C++ Rules may cause a violation to be raised, in situations where the method used is necessary.

Because of this, MISRA C provides a mechanism for Deviating a Rule - and this would be the appropriate route for you to follow... please do not try and find a way around the Rule using "clever" code!

As highlighted by this question, accessing specific memory (and/or I/O devices) is one particular case.  In fact, one of the examples included in MISRA C:2012 shows this exact use case as being non-compliant with the Rule.

In 2016, the MISRA C Working Group published additional guidance on Compliance, including enhancing the Deviation process... this gives help on what is a justifiable Deviation - and accessing hardware is one of those!

In due course, it is planned to provide more "layered" guidance... but that will not be immediate.

[Please note profile for disclaimer]