# GCC variable mapping and MISRA-C

Tags: c, gcc, stm32, misra

I know mostly two ways (with many variants, use bifields, data structures per peripheral, etc...) to declare memory mapped registers with GCC:

- either use a pointer initaliased to the right adress like `volatile uint32_t *pMyRegister = (uint32_t *)0xDEADBEEFUL;`
- or define a variable and map it manually like `volatile uint32_t MyRegister __attribute((section(".register_section")));` and then map the section in the LD file.

Unfortunately none of these ways seem compatible with MISRA-C coding rules, the first one because there is an unauthorized (by MISRA) cast from integer to pointer, the second because of the attribute keyword.

My question is: is there a way (with the second solution) to map a variable in a section without affecting the ANSIness of the code (ie. no compiler specific keyword).

Thank you

Comment: Note: sometimes you may write code that directly interacts with hardware (or low-level specific details): MISRA-C allows you to break certain rules (it's called a deviation) if you can justify that the rule must be broken in that very specific situation in order to allow a low-level interaction. MISRA cannot validate low-level specific things, since it is more a "general-purpose" set of rules. [See also this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49408077/misra-11-3-cast-from-int-to-pointer).

Comment: Which MISRA-C version are you using?

Comment: @LucaPolito MISRA-C can and should absolutely validate low-level things, it is used on the source as whole. For things that it definitely can't validate such as inline assembler, there's special rules for how to deal with such code too.

Comment: @Lundin Yes, you're correct. I didn't mean that MISRA-C cannot be used to validate low-level programs, I just meant that it cannot validate low-level-specific aspects like, for instance, that address `0xABCD` is a valid hardware address. MISRA-C is platform-agnostic. Particular care must be taken when you have low-level programs, because MISRA-C often requires human validation for that kind of things (like justified deviation from a rule).

Answer (score 3):

First of all, neither is correct because of missing `volatile`. See [How to access a hardware register from firmware?](https://electrical.codidact.com/posts/276290) which also briefly addresses MISRA-C.

To answer the question, this rule MISRA-C:2012 11.4 is advisory and comes with a rationale that says (the note in the end was appended by me):

> "...but may be necessary when addressing memory mapped registers or other hardware specific features. If casting between integers and pointers is used, care should be taken..." [to not cause misalignment undefined behavior]

So you can safely ignore this rule for your register declarations and if needed refer to the rationale of rule 11.4. Since it is advisory, no deviation is required (but preferably you should document that you ignore the rule still).

Notably the former of your two versions is preferable from a MISRA-C perspective, since it doesn't contain non-standard extensions that you need to document how they are used, which is otherwise required as per other MISRA rules.

Comment: Yeah, I forgot the `volatile`of course, will edit it.

Comment: Your comment makes lot of sense, however it does not strictly answer my question ( about variable mapping in linker script). Actually I might have found a simple solution. gcc is able to create a section per variable. I don't have one variable per register but one variable per peripheral. So I would just have to map , say the section `.bss.My_SPI_Registers` at the right adress, it is done only in ld file

Comment: @GuillaumePetitjean The `#define` macro version as per the link I posted is what I've used in the past when MISRA compliance of _everything_ was required - including libraries. The linker script tricks version has the advantage of those objects actually appearing in the debugger, but then you should be using a debugger with target awareness anyway, so that's a dubious advantage (but one the tool venders state as excuse for using non-standard syntax).

Comment: Thank you , good to know you used the macro solution in projects where MISRA was enforced. We also have a question regarding the unit tests. These tests are done on a different platform (typically unix or linux) so the macro solution is not very adapted because the registers need to be defined as regular variables and mapped in normal RAM in this context. Not very practical to do with the macros solution and we are required to unit test exactly the same C code.

Comment: @GuillaumePetitjean You cannot make any form of serious tests on microcontroller firmware outside the intended target. Testing needs to be integrated in the product with serial interfaces, logs, pogo pins or whatever makes sense. Higher layers can be tested on a PC, but obviously not the drivers or real-time characteristics.

Comment: I would expect better of you @Lundin... you **cannnot** *safely ignore this rule* - but you can **disapply** it (with rationale)

Comment: @Andrew Well, it _is_ pretty safe to ignore since the only place where you do explicit integer/pointer conversions is low level code like register maps and memory-handling drivers, where the programmer tends to know what they are doing and not cause misalignment. Note that C does _not_ allow implicit integer/pointer conversions, contrary to popular belief.

Comment: Unfortunately people think you can **ignore** Advisory Guidelines - you can't **just** ignore them though.

Comment: @Andrew Advisory rules would have gotten a higher status if there weren't so many questionable rules with advisory status. This particular rule is just burdensome since it cannot be enforced on low-level code. The only true danger is misalignment as a result from integer to pointer conversion, so it would have been better to have a rule addressing that specifically. Though I can't really say that I've ever encountered a bug in real-world embedded systems where an explicit conversion from int caused misalignment. The few misalignment bugs I can recall were related to linker scripts and such.